# Insert bitmap inside a nsis label

Tags: nsis, nsdialogs

I am trying to construct a page with has a horizontal area with coloured background. I did this using an empty label. Displaying no text and just fill color inside it. 
On top on this now I want to add an image.

I  `${NSD_CreateLabel}`  first and then after this wrote code for 
`${NSD_CreateBitmap}`  and  `${NSD_SetImage}`. I adjusted the X Y coordinates for image such that it sits on the label. 
However, when I compile script, I only see the label. No bitmap image is displayed on top of it.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Can you post your code? I suppose you are creating dialog with nsDialogs. Try to create bitmap without label - maybe label is placed over the bitmap.

Comment: What I want to achieve is say vertical column with certain color and put an image that blends on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The z-index (depth) of created controls is not defined/documented but in your case you should be able to just swap them so the label is not on top of the image:

```
Page Custom myPageCreate
Page InstFiles

!include nsDialogs.nsh
Function myPageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateBitmap} 30% 30% 80% 80% ""
Pop $0
File "/oname=$pluginsdir\img.bmp" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\arrow.bmp"
${NSD_SetImage} $0 "$pluginsdir\img.bmp" $1

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 50% 50% "Hello"
Pop $0
SetCtlColors $0 000000 ff00cc

nsDialogs::Show
${NSD_FreeImage} $1
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks Anders. It worked. I have similar work that I want to achieve with buttons.